# Can someone help me understand this grammar?

Tags: grammar, dsl, xtext

I can't understand these grammar rules, and what the "returns" and "current" keywords means ?

```
WhereEntry returns WhereEntry:
AndWhereEntry ({OrWhereEntry.entries+=current} 
    ("OR" entries+=AndWhereEntry)+)?
;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `returns` means: the result of the rule will be of type `WhereEntry`.
2. `current` means: the object parsed so far.

In sum this will mean

- `AndWhereEntry` is a Subclass of `WhereEntry`.
- if there is an `OR` then the `AndWhereEntry` parsed before will
  be added to the `OrWhereEntry` entries list.